# Creating layout that automatically takes several rows when shrinked

Tags: qt, layout

Is it possible to create such a layout as the one Total Commander uses for displaying drive buttons in the toolbar? Below is the picture of how it takes 2 rows when not all widgets fit a single row, that's exactly what I need to achieve:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FlowLayout:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/graphicsview-flowlayout.html

TotalCommander was not made however with QT but with Delphi and (FreePascal lately).

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking whether it's possible and not just how to achieve this :) Thanks for the link, I have honestly never heard of FlowLayout.